# MySQL Error in multiple table UPDATE

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE TBL_LABELS SET TMP.column_value = LBL.label_desc, TMP.info_value=LBL.helptext
       FROM TBL_LABELS TMP
       INNER JOIN hh_label_mast LBL ON TMP.column_name=LBL.lbl_id
       WHERE page_id in(as_page_id ,'HHGENPGID')
       AND lang_cd= as_langcd;
```

While executing this I am getting an error like "right syntax to use near `FROM TBL_LABELS TMP
           INNER JOIN hh_label_mast LBL ON TMP.column_name=LBL.lbl_`"

Can you please give me the right syntax?

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be a `FROM` clause in the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) syntax. You may want to try:

```
UPDATE      tbl_labels TMP
INNER JOIN  hh_label_mast LBL ON (TMP.column_name = LBL.lbl_id)
SET         TMP.column_value = LBL.label_desc, 
            TMP.info_value = LBL.helptext
WHERE       page_id IN(as_page_id ,'HHGENPGID') AND lang_cd = as_langcd;
```